# How do I solve a probability problem using programming? I have a solution but I do not know how to model it into a computer program

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> Statement: A family has two children. At least one child is a boy born on a Tuesday. What is the probability that the other one is also a boy?

> Answer: 13/27

The complete solution:

> The given information alters the sample space, which has grown by a
> factor of $7 * 7$, now that the birthday of the week for each child is
> a factor.
>
> Let $w$ represent a birthday that falls on any day of the week and $t$
> be Tuesday.
>
> If the boy born on a Tuesday is the younger child there are two
> possibilities permitted by the given condition: $\{GwBt, BwBt\}$. If
> he's the older one, then there are also two possibilities: $\{BtBw,
> > BtGw\}$. In combining these sets, we must be careful to remove the
> duplicated $BtBt$, which is included in both the $BwBt$ and $BtBw$
> cases.
> The combined set is thus: $\{GwBt, BwBt, BtBw, BtGw\} - \{BtBt\}$. The set has $7 (GwBt) + 7 (BwBt) + 7 (BtBw) + 7 (BtGw) - 1 (BtBt) = 27$ elements. Of those, $7 (BwBt) + 7 (BtBw) - 1 (BtBt) = 13$
> have two boys, giving $13/27 \sim 0.48$.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question. In any case the question doesn't require any computing.

Comment: @NickCox You may check the correct answer below. Thanks for your attention

Comment: I think you miss my point: The title of a question should always correspond to what is in the question. There is nothing in your question about what kind of answer you seek.

Comment: @NickCox Well Noted! I will keep it in mind. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Why not fix it now? We appreciate your good manners but editing the question is the positive reaction to take.

Comment: @NickCox I believe my question is fine. I respect your opinion.

Comment: Noted, and for the sake of openness I record a downvote for the question being unclear.

Comment: (-1) This question should have a `self-study` tag and much more details on the reasons for asking the question and being uable to solve it on one's own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is a simple model using `python`:

```
import numpy as np

num_trials = 1000000
denom, num = 0, 0

for i in range(num_trials):
    # boy: 0, girl: 1
    # monday=0, tuesday=1, ...
    gender = np.random.randint(2, size=2)
    day = np.random.randint(7, size=2)
    
    if ((gender == 0) * (day == 1)).sum() > 0:
        # at least one boy with Tuesday as birthday
        denom += 1
        
        if (gender == 0).sum() == 2:
            # both are boys
            num += 1

print(num / denom, 13/27)
```

And, its output is

```
0.48442138657663425 0.48148148148148145
```

which are close enough.

Comment: Wow!! You made my day!!! This is so perfect. Thank You

Comment: I am learning this concept. Can you help to solve another example? I have a solution. I have uploaded it as a question as well.

Comment: Problem Statement: It is known that a drunkard will go out to drink 90% of his days and he only goes to three fixed bars for drinking. Today, the police searched two of the bars and didn’t find him. What is the probability of drunkard in the third house?

Answer: 0.90 or 90%

Comment: @AdilAbid No need to ask your [new question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/492096/930) as a follow-up comment.

Comment: @chl Thank you. I am new to this community. Thanks for your kind attention and support

Comment: Good insofar as the answer pleased the OP, and acceptance and upvotes are fitting reward for your work. I am disturbed by the thought that showing how to do this using any number of other languages or packages would be just as valid an answer. As often, there is a grey area between using code to illustrate an answer and addressing questions asking for code.